# How to create a new view on iOS project based on phone gap?

Tags: html, ios, cordova

I used Phonegap as the basic framework to built my IOS project. In order to write a native function, I wrote a plugin and wanna to used objc to create a new view. However, I failed to create it. What should I do next?

Comment: you dont create views with native code. view is html

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and understand Cordova plugins to bridge between native code and Phonegap HTML5